# installing lubuntu on nvme on legacy mobo

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, lubuntu

I cannot figure out how to install lubuntu on my nvme ssd. One issue is the legacy mobo. I did get manjaro to install and boot but cannot find a way to replicate the process in lubuntu. Can someone please point me to an articulation of the steps?

Here are the steps I used with the manjaro installer:

1. KDE Partition Manager to partition and format nvme ssd with msdos table and ext4 fs. Mount point is /.
2. KDE Partition Manager to partition and format a usb stick to use for booting. Structure is:

gpt table;

8mb unformatted empty space at start of stick, flagged as bios-grub;

rest of stick formatted as ext4, mount point is /boot

3. Set installer to install / to nvme ssd
4. Set installer to install bootloader to mbr of stick

That's it. I haven't been able to replicate this process with the lubuntu installer. It would be much appreciated if someone could amend my process list here to make it work for lubuntu.

edit:
This link is to my original question on this subject but it only pertains to the general process as manjaro compares to ubuntu. I've since entered into a much more custom or manual install process but have hit roadblocks. Hopefully, this posting begins to get more specific about the problem.

[ubuntu studio install /boot to another drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352671/ubuntu-studio-install-boot-to-another-drive)

edit:
I downloaded the lubuntu iso on the 15th, just a couple of days ago. The filename is - lubuntu-20.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso. If it's useful for comparison, the manjaro iso file I installed from was this - manjaro-kde-21.0.7-210614-linux510.iso. I think they both use the Calamares installer.

thanks,
babag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ubuntu studio install /boot to another drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352671/ubuntu-studio-install-boot-to-another-drive)

Comment: thanks for the reply but no. that posting was my preliminary question on this subject and only addresses whether the process is as simple in ubuntu as manjaro. i've since gone into a much more manual process, as detailed above, and have hit roadblocks. this current posting pertains more to the specifics of getting around those blocks than to the generality of the process' complexity.

Comment: You've provided no release details; so I don't know which software stack you're talking about; let alone which installer (only one installer is supported; but Lubuntu has provided three in the recent past which can still be downloaded from Ubuntu). Without release specifics; I cannot know what issues you may encounter as I know nothing about what software stack you're asking about.  Since Manjaro installed; you can use the software-stack comparison to work out how to get Lubuntu installed - that will contain your answers.

Comment: Thanks, guiverc. I've never heard the term 'software stack' before so I don't quite follow what's being suggested. One thing I can say is that I downloaded lubuntu on the 15th so, very recently. The filename has the release version if that helps: lubuntu-20.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso. I hope this info is of some use. thanks again.

Comment: For comparison, the manjaro file I installed from is: manjaro-kde-21.0.7-210614-linux510.iso

Comment: Also asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2465031